# CGAL: Remove constraints in triangulation according to some face property

Tags: constraints, cgal, delaunay

Suppose I have a constrained Delaunay triangulation where the facets are associated to some 'label' (some abstract property). I want to remove from the constraints the edges which are incident to facets that share the same labels. What is an efficient approach to do it, and how to make sure the facets obtained after a constrained is removed keeps its label?

Here is an piece of code apadted from a CGAL example to illustrate my purpose:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <iostream>

struct FaceInfo2
{
  FaceInfo2(){}
  int label;
};

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel       K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K>                      Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2<FaceInfo2,K>    Fbb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K,Fbb>        Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb>               TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag                                Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, TDS, Itag>  CDT;
typedef CDT::Point                                                Point;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K>                                        Polygon_2;


void insert_polygon(CDT& cdt,const Polygon_2& polygon)
{
  if ( polygon.is_empty() ) return;
  CDT::Vertex_handle v_prev=cdt.insert(*CGAL::cpp11::prev(polygon.vertices_end()));
  for (Polygon_2::Vertex_iterator vit=polygon.vertices_begin();
       vit!=polygon.vertices_end();++vit)
  {
    CDT::Vertex_handle vh=cdt.insert(*vit);
    cdt.insert_constraint(vh,v_prev);
    v_prev=vh;
  }  
}

void compute_labels(CDT& cdt)
{
  // Do stuff and set the 'label' of each facet according to some property
}

int main( )
{
  // Insert some polyons into a constrained triangulation
  CDT cdt;
  insert_polygon(cdt,polygon1);
  insert_polygon(cdt,polygon2); // ...

  // Mark facets according to an arbitrary property
  compute_labels(cdt);

  int count=0;
  for (CDT::Finite_edges_iterator eit=cdt.finite_edges_begin();
                                  eit!=cdt.finite_edges_end();++eit)
  {
    // This will not do, because the iterator may get invalidated
    if ( eit->first->info().label == eit->first->neighbor(eit->second)->info().label )
      cdt.remove_constrained_edge(eit->first, eit->second);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I see several possibilties from there on:

1. Build a new CDT by inserting constrains that only join faces with different labels in the original triangulation.
2. Use the variant `cdt.remove_constrained_edge(fh, i, out)` to recover the facets possibly affected by the constraint removal, and treat them accordingly (but it still leaves the issue of the iterator being invalidated).
3. Use a BFS/DFS traversal of the facets coupled with the previous remark, but I still I'd still need to know which queued/stacked facet was affected by each constraint removal.
4. Use a `set` instead of a `queue` / `stack` during the traversal, so I can remove from facets I need to visit the handle to facets incident to a removed constraint (before removal), since after the removal they may be invalidated (if a flip occurs).

So, what do StackOverflow think about this?

Comment: As you have discover by yourself, the question is complicated. I would to know more about your high-level goal. Maybe constrained Delaunay triangulations are not the tool you really need. It might be that a conform triangulation is more suited for your needs. Can you explain briefly why you want to use a constrained triangulation, and why you want to remove several constrained edges?

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant, as the question seems interesting enough in itself, but I'll provide more insight on what I'm trying to achieve. I have an object whose mesh I want to "beautify", and I know that its facets are delimited by convex polygons and which ones lie on the identical planes. So I project those on an axis-aligned plane, and I want to keep only the "boundary edges" as constraints, and be able to retrieve the interior of the mesh (the label property I mentioned in my question).

Comment: Your original question is difficult, and you already give several hints of solution.

If your mesh was processed by `make_conforming_Delaunay_2`, from the CGAL Mesh_2 package http://www.cgal.org/Pkg/Mesh_2 then the removal of a constrain would not flip edges, because the constrained Delaunay triangulation would also be a (unconstrained) Delaunay triangulation.

Comment: Hi. Well my mesh wasn't processed by `make_conforming_Delaunay_2`, it's really nothing special (appart that faces are made of convex polyhedrons). But hey I think I'll just make do with and work with the specific condiditons I'm working with. In the meantime maybe you could add as a wishlist feature to improve the validity of iterators and make this kind of question easier to tackle for the end user?

Comment: Then I suggest you to call `make_conforming_Delaunay_2` on your mesh. That will insert extra vertices on your constraints, but you will be able to remove constraints without any flip of edges.